# how do you stop scammers

Tags: money-transfer

just wondering if you can stop scams

Comment: Any specific type of scam has caught your attention?

Answer (score 1):

If you were talking about Fake Bitcoin Transactions, The best way to avoid any type of that is **Waiting at least for 6 confirmations**

I've read many articles about that, and the final answer is waiting for six bitcoin network confirmations.

You can read more about [irreversible_Transactions](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Irreversible_Transactions).